# xslt encoding special characters

Tags: java, xslt, xslt-1.0, xalan

I'm using Java with **Xalan 2.7** to transform one XML to another.

Source is `StreamSource(UTF-8 Reader);`
Result is `StreamResult(ByteArrayOutputStream)`

Now my template is set to use **UTF-8** (note the version 1.0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" 
            indent="yes" 
            omit-xml-declaration="yes"  
            encoding="UTF-8"/>
```

Now I want that output would have all special characters encoded. Something like `2.0` character map, so that `€ = &#euro;` or hex equivalent.

How to do this with least effort?

Comment: As long as the **consumer** understand XML, it wouldn't make any difference to use encoded or actual characters. **Problems come for using XML instances with some application that doesn't understand XML.**

Comment: If you use `html` serialization method, characters outside encoding range might end up being encode with character references or HTML entities, but it's implementation dependant wich one is going to happen.

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume that by "special" characters you mean anything outside of the ASCII range.

If you don't want those characters in your resulting XML, then you don't need to specify UTF-8 as the encoding, since you won't have any non-ASCII characters in your content directly.

You can simply specify `ASCII` as the [output encoding](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-XML-Output-Method) on your XSLT stylesheet to get the XSLT processor to output [numeric character references](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#dt-charref) for all non-ASCII characters.

Both the JDK 6 default processor as well as Xalan 2.7 support this.

Comment: Interesting, did not know that, nice

Answer (score 0):

I once had a similar requirement because I needed to process unprintable chars through XSLT.
I came up with using a FilterInputStream/FilterOutputStream which used a small finite state automata to marshal and unmarshal such notation.
Hope this gives you some ideas :-)